# Angular validator makes my $scope unavailable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a simple input in my html page :

```
<input type="text" class='form-control' id='card' name="myCard" ng-model='form.cardNb' card-validation>
```

I created a function 'cadType' which returns a value according the first char in this input :

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

        mainApp.controller('formController', function($scope) {
           $scope.form = {
              cardNb: "",
              nameOnCard: "",
              expiryDate: "",
              CVV:  "",
              cardType: function() {
                 var firstCharCard;
                 var secondCharCard;
                 firstCharCard = $scope.form.cardNb.charAt(0);
                 secondCharCard = $scope.form.cardNb.charAt(1);
             //some additional logic here...
```

(function works fine at this moment , no problem)

then, I created a new validator to do some validation on this input :

```
    mainApp.directive('cardValidation', function() {
    return {

        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.cardValidation = function(value) {  
                return (value.length == 13);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

This validation works perfectly but my function doesn't work anymore !
I get this error when filling the input :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
    at Object.$scope.form.cardType (index.html:86)
    at ib.functionCall (angular.js:12404)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:12813)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:14300)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at eg.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.js:23391)
    at eg.$setViewValue (angular.js:23363)
    at HTMLInputElement.l (angular.js:19784)
    at HTMLInputElement.c (angular.js:3032)
```

I suppose that my validation makes unavailable my scope ... what can I do for that ?

Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How validators work is that they create the model if the validation fails.

In your case if the length is not 13 then the underlying model will be cleared `form.cardNb`.

So in your function you should explicitly check for `cardNb` to be not null before using charAt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if the scope is cleared when not validated then I've an issue. I need to get the values anyway. Maybe it's preferable to use javascript classic in my function ?

Comment: If you are on Angular 1.3, can you check `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions